# send typing notification in MSBOT framework in node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have developed a bot in Bot framework. Once user responds to the bot and bot is processing it, i need to show the typing indicator to the user in the meanwhile for  every 2 seconds . It should be working across all conversations of the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy as pie. Node.js bots send a typing indicator to the user by executing `session.SendTyping();`

If you want to see what this looks like in the framework, you can find the [code here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/7b70cfd/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L1770)
Also, Microsoft has a [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) that talks specifically about this.

Comment: Hi @Ed Boykin, Thanks for your response.  I have used session.sendTyping(); in my code but it is disappearing within 2 to 3 seconds, but the operation which i am performing is running for 45 seconds. I need that typing notification for 45 seconds. Meanwhile, Could you please  where  to place this sendTyping function in the code, do i want to use this sendTyping in all the functions?

Comment: Ah, yes. This is a common complaint. Unfortunately, the length of time is a function of the chatbot channel and not the bot framework. You could try to send the SendTyping() command in a separate thread with a solid method for telling it to stop. I've never tried it so I'm not sure how effective it would be